# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI Only in IIS Publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webapi

So I have read almost all the answers but I couldn't find anytging about my problem.

In my asp.net application I use the Vintasoft Barcode Reader controls.

Everything is fine in my development environment, it works.

In my WebApiConfig I have :

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DemoAPI",
        routeTemplate: "vintasoft/api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
 }
```

In my global asax.cs :

```
 System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

When I publish this application, I have this error message :

```
 <Error>
  <Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://www.example.com/vintasoft/api/MyVintasoftBarcodeApi/ReadBarcodesFromBase64'.</Message>
 <MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'MyVintasoftBarcodeApi'.</MessageDetail>
 </Error>
```

Is there something to configure in ISS?

Any idea, please?

Comment: Please check that the name of the controller class follows standard naming conventions. In ASP.NET Web API, ApiControllers class names need to be suffixed with "Controller", such as "MyVintasoftBarcodeApiController". `public class MyVintasoftBarcodeApiController : ApiController
{}`